# Group of the form $\langle a,b\mid a^4 =b^4=1 = (ab)^2,ab^3=ba^3\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, definition

I have seen the notion of a group

$$G_{4,4}=\langle a,b\mid a^4 = b^4=1 = (ab)^2, ab^3=ba^3\rangle$$

of order $16$. Is there any generalization of this structure to any arbitrary $n$ i. e.

$$G_{n,n}=\langle a,b\mid a^n = b^n=1 = (ab)^2, ab^{n-1}=ba^{n-1}\rangle.$$

I am not able to see that this is a group of order $n^2.$ Please help me figure out this generalization.

Comment: Is this quasi-dihedral group of order 16?

Comment: How would you prove that the group $G_{4,4}$ has order $4^2=16$? And can you see why $G_{n,n}$ has order *at most* $n^2$?

Comment: @user1729 you can find it here https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-e&q=Units+of+Group+Algebras+of+Non-Abelian+Groups+of+Order+16+and+Exponent+4+over+F2k

Comment: @nozalp10 thanks for the reply.

Comment: @user1729 , but I am not able to see about the order $G_{n,n}$

Comment: @MANI I'm not asking for myself - I'm asking in the hope that you can briefly explain the proof to us, and so understand what would be needed for the more general proof.

Comment: It seems to me that $a^2$ and $b^2$ necessarily commute. After all, $(ab)^2=1$ implies that $ab=b^{-1}a^{-1}$. On the other hand, the last relation reads $ba^{-1}=ab^{-1}$. Therefore
$$ab^2a^{-1}=(ab)(ba^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}ab^{-1}=b^{-2}.$$
The claim follows from this. Now, if $n$ is odd, this implies that $a$ and $b$ commute, and the group is abelian.

Comment: Use a small program in GAP for making light: `f:=FreeGroup("a","b");;  
a:=f.1;;  b:=f.2;;  
G:=f/[a^n,b^n, (a*b)^2, a*b^(n-1)*a^(-n+1)*b^(-1)];;
Size(G);`

Comment: @Mikasa I have never used the GAP.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen if we add this extra condition,can we claim that order og the group is $n^2.$

Comment: (cont'd) Still assuming $n$ odd, the last relation becomes $b^{n-2}=a^{n-2}$, implying $b^2=a^2$.  Together with $(ab)^2=1$, now reading $a^2b^2=1$, this implies $a^4=b^4=1$. This leads me to the conclusion, that if $n$ is odd, the group is trivial.

Comment: What extra condition? Anyway, like user1729, I would like to see you explain why $G_{4,4}$ has order sixteen.

Comment: Also, you should have taken the feedback of "Please provide additional context" from your (very related) previous question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4482706/10513

Comment: Jyrki Lahtonen has shown that this group is trivial when $n$ is odd. It has order $n^2$ when $n$ is even, but that does not seem partricularly easy to prove. You can do it by noting that the subgroup $N := \langle a,b^2 \rangle$ has index $2$ in $G$, and $G$ is the semidirect product of $N$ with $\langle ab \rangle$, but that is a bit technical and it would be nice to see and easier proof.

Comment: I spotted that the mapping $a\mapsto (1234)(5678)$, $b\mapsto (1652)(3874)$ gives rise to a homomorphism $f:G_{4,4}\to S_8$ We have $f(ab)=(17)(35)$ and $f(ab^3)=f(ba^3)=(13)(26)(48)(57)$.

Comment: (cont'd) Here $f(a^2)$ commutes with $f(b)$, and it is easy to check that the image $f(G_{4,4})$ has order $16$. But this does not imply that the action is faithful. Also, when searching for $f$ I used what I knew about Sylow $2$-subgroups of $S_8$, so generalizing that may be a tall order.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I tried a lot to derive the relation $a^{n-2}=b^{n-2}$? Please give me some hints to prove this.

Comment: @MANI That was only in the case of an odd $n$. After I had shown the group to be abelian, when you can simply cancel one $a$ and one $b$ from the last relation. I tried to convey that with *(cont'd)*, indicating that this is a continuation of my previous comment. Sorry about not making all that clear.